# mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' error while copying table

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, excel, import

I am creating function to MySQL database manager to import excel files into table.
But the problem is in backup system, I copy existing tables with ***some*** data, and copying works, and there are new table (table name + current time and date).
Then program try to push excel file into table, and I got following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\c1v\PycharmProjects\Python_Exel\PhoneExel\import_tester.py", line 7, in <module>
    c.import_excel("import_test_1", "C:\\Users\\c1v\\Desktop\\cats.xls")
  File "C:\Users\c1v\PycharmProjects\Python_Exel\PhoneExel\db_manager.py", line 94, in import_excel
    self.operator.executemany(q, l)
  File "C:\Users\c1v\PycharmProjects\Python_Exel\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 654, in executemany
    return self.execute(stmt)
  File "C:\Users\c1v\PycharmProjects\Python_Exel\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\c1v\PycharmProjects\Python_Exel\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\c1v\PycharmProjects\Python_Exel\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Code:

```
def import_excel(self, table, file_loc):
    print(f"Importing excel file into table: {table}...")
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("-%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")
    table_name = table + dt_string
    self.operator.execute(f"CREATE TABLE `{table_name}` LIKE `{table}`")
    self.operator.execute(f"INSERT INTO `{table_name}` SELECT * FROM `{table}`")
    l = list()
    xlsx_file = xlrd.open_workbook(file_loc)
    sheet = xlsx_file.sheet_by_index(0)
    sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
    max_row = sheet.nrows
    print(max_row)
    for i in range(1, 4):
        l.append(tuple(sheet.row_values(i)))
    q = f"insert into {table} (ID, name, fav_food, loud_level, cute_level) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    self.operator.executemany(q, l)
    self.db.commit()
    # self.db.close()
    print(f"Successfully imported excel file into table: {table}")a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you have defined ID as a unique primary key, i.e, the table parameter you pass on to import excel, defines ID as primary key and your excel sheet has entries with identical IDs, now to overcome this, you either have to modify/ update/ delete these rows from your excel sheet, or you can just specify that ID is not a primary key. MySQL raises an integrity error as primary keys are used to uniquely identify rows/tuples/entries in table.